# how to get the checkbox id from xml file and display it to the page in android?

Tags: java

i want to get the id of this checkbox to display it on page. how do i do that? i've tried getting it by calling the function .getId() but it shows another different id. thank you in advance for your help.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/bi16160241"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="Elvin Malih (BI16160241)" />
```

Comment: You already know the ID because you put it in the XML, so why would you need to programatically retrieve it?  You also have it hardcoded in the text field, so that begs the question: What do you mean by "display it to the page?"  In fact what do you mean by "it"?  We are all assuming you mean the ID, but do you mean how do you display a checkbox?

Comment: Can you just explain properly why you want do this nonsense thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view.getId() numeric value.you can use this line of code

```
String id=  getResources().getResourceEntryName(checkBox.getId())
```

but if you want to pass some data use tag property of view

Answer (score 0):

You can set `onclickListener` on the checkbox and in your `onclick` method

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       String name = v.getTag().toString();
}
```